# Old Seal help for an ignorant American

Tags: translation, traditional-characters, seal

Have had this a long time, have tried previously to find info was unsuccessful.
Any help would be appreciated
I've looked up context clues in regards to types of horses, hair style of rider, floral pattern on saddle with little success. I wish I could add more images to get the individual seals
[painting[image]

Answer (score 2):

the picture is called “牧馬圖” by 韓幹. well, the real one, is in taiwan national palace museum

https://theme.npm.edu.tw/selection/Article.aspx?sNo=04009118

alors, one might assume that you’ve a imitation

have fun :)